# Querying rails database from the ClientSide using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that displays a table (tr) of businesses. When a user clicks on  a business row on the frontend I want to query my rails database grab all the reviews associated with that business and dynamically render that on the same page. I'm not too sure what's the best way to go about doing this, but was thinking of building a route to query the database with jQuery AJAX. I'm currently getting a 404 error and not sure what part I have wrong.

My event listener in my app.js

```
    $(function(){
      $("#home-table").on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var businessName = $(this).find(".business-name").text();
       $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:3000/query_business?name=" + businessName,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(server_data) {
          console.log(server_data);  #I will eventually parse out json data 
        }).fail(function() {
          console.log("fail");
       });
     });
```

Here's what I think I should have in my controller.

```
   class BusinessController < ApplicationController
      def query_business
         @business = Business.find(name: params[:name])  
         @ratings = @business.ratings

         respond_to do |format|
           format.json { render :json => @ratings }
         end
      end
    end
```

In my routes.rb

```
    get '/query_business', to: 'business#query_business', as: :query_business
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@business = Business.find_by(name: params[:name])
```

Or

```
@business = Business.where(name: params[:name]).first
```

I think method `find` is expecting an `id` of that record. You get 404, might because it could not find a business record.